# Incorporate custom advanced search in 'DSpace 4.2 version' XMLUI theme

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace

How can i incorporate search by using one/more than one metadata in dspace 4.2 version? I can't understand which is the exact file(in xmlui theme),where i have to edit to do it.
I have modify dspace search panel.Now user can search through Author,Year etc. But that search not working. Please help me.

The advanced search box will look something like this:

[image]

other fields will be added subsequently.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "incorporate search by using one/more than one metadata"? Do you want your users to search other metadata aside from the default title, author, subject, date issued?

Comment: I want to add a custom advanced search feature which will include certain metadata fields. Initially I am trying to implement the search based on default metadata. And If i am successful,I will include other metadata fields. I have not yet been able to understand the flow of search request,can you please help.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: [What is a search filter](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Discovery#Discovery-WhatisaSearchFilter). Make sure to run `dspace index-discovery -b` after modifying the searchFIlters and/or sidebarFacets

Comment: Based on your screenshot where you add radio buttons for each metadata that you would like to add, I wonder why, when the (search)results can be achieved by just using the discovery feature (which is enabled by default in dspace 4x)?

Comment: We are defining our own metadata standard,which will include some additional fields apart from those already present in DC standard. Those fields will be used for advanced search.

Comment: I hope this lines can help you: (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4.2/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/core/navigation.xsl#L54-#L115). This is from the default search bar. You can make this as the basis for your radio buttons and values.

Comment: If you follow the suggestion @euler to use the discovery features, you can configure your own metadata fields into the discovery search.

Comment: I think it will be more beneficial if I can get the underlying code of the search box in the second screenshot. I want to understand how that "Apply" button works,which files should I look into?